# Cloud Run for Anthos http2 unexpected EOF error | Google Cloud Platform

Tags: websocket, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-run, knative

I deployed service on Google Cloud Run for Anthos. When I deploy with Http2 enabled I get this error

```
unexpected EOF
```

and sometimes randomly

```
read tcp 127.0.0.1:39130->127.0.0.1:80: read: connection reset by peer
```

If I deploy with it off everything works fine expect WebSockets. The purpose of migrating Cloud Run for Anthos was to add WebSocket support.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Cloud Run on Anthos Official Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/anthos/multicluster-management/connect/troubleshooting?hl=zh-CN#oauth_error), the error `read tcp 127.0.0.1:39130->127.0.0.1:80: read: connection reset by peer` is caused because the URL you are trying to access is not allowed by your HTTP proxy.

To mitigate this issue, please check that your HTTP proxy allowlist includes the following URLs/domains:

```
gkeconnect.googleapis.com
oauth2.googleapis.com/token
www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs
```

Comment: Hello Nibrass, did you get your websocket issue resolved by following the instruction referred in the answer? An FYI, if you use Cloud Run for Anthos with custom domain mapping, you need to manually add a patch to make websocket work https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/gke/troubleshooting#using_websockets_with_custom_domains